# Window casing and conversion from inch thick drywall to half inch

Tags: windows, trim

I'm renovating the bathroom. I used to have 1" thick drywall and I'm lowering it to 1/2" thick drywall (so the window sticks out of the wall 1" now).

What are my options for trimming the window? Inch thick trim seems really thick. Is that normal?

Here are pictures of my attempted explanation...
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

1. Use a second layer of 1/2" drywall to bring the wall flush to the
   window;
2. Trim the window casing down by 1/2"; or
3. Use inch thick
   trim on the window casing.

Personally I recommend #2 and would use what's called a Japanese saw:

[image]

or a multi-tool with a wood blade

[image]

to trim the casing down to be flush with the wall.

Comment: The [Ryōba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_saw) has become very popular lately.

Comment: If I trim the casing, won't the window still stick into the room that far? I actually have a replacement window that fits the current window size (bought it before I realized I would want it to be thinner)

Comment: Ok perhaps I misunderstood your meaning.  Could you post a picture of the window?

Comment: I've added pics. See my edit :)

Comment: So I think perhaps we're using different meanings for terms here.  The casing I talk about trimming is the wood you're measuring.  You would install the drywall, then using the tools I indicated, cut the casing to be flush with the drywall.